# Why does a function created in one js file not work when called or even created in another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm really hoping someone can explain why i'm hitting errors. 
I suspect i don't understand something fundamental, and hoping I can learn something here.

You can see it not working here: http://syndex.me

> I have commented the relevant parts of the scripts to make it easy to
>   find.

I have an image resizing script, which reduces the height of an image *if* the image is bigger then the window. It works on any image initially loaded, **but not the newly loaded posts brought in by my infinite scroll script** --> http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.syndex.js

It uses ".each" and within that, ".load"
".load" does not bubble up the DOM structure, thus i can't bind it to a ".live" or a ".delegate" event.

So my next step has been to try and kick this function in again directly within the infinite scroll script. Surely that would make sense? That script is here http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.infinitescrollfortumblr.js

If i copy and paste the working script from jquery.syndex.js, i get error after error, it's like i'm talking a different language. The code itself is not mine, and it uses pretty abstract variables to describe everything.

How can i adapt the image resizing function to work in the infinitescrollfortumblr.js?

Answer (score 0):

Your functions don't work cross script because they've been create *inside a closure* and are therefore only visible within that closure's scope.

Either put them in the global scope (bleuch) using `window.funcname = function() { ... }`, or create your own namespace object for them:

```
NAMESPACE = NAMESPACE || {};
NAMESPACE.myfunc = function() { ... };
```

Comment: Sorry, (bleuch) as in not nice, wouldn't do it?

Comment: I really don't understand the above, would be great if you could clarify!

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the stock infinite scroll script, then place your resize script in it's callback:

```
$(elem).infinitescroll(options,function(){
  // your resize code
});
```

Comment: is that going to work on tumblr though, considering they made a plugin specifically for wordpress?